# Saving scikit-learn classifier causes memory error

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pickle

My machine has 16G RAM and the training program uses memory up to 2.6G.
But when I want to save the classifier (trained using `sklearn.svm.SVC` from a large dataset) as pickle file, it consumes too much memory that my machine cannot give. Eager to know any alternative approaches to save an classifier.

I've tried:

- `pickle` and `cPickle`
- Dump as `w` or `wb`
- Set `fast = True`

Neither of them work, always raise a MemoryError. Occasionally the file was saved, but loading it causes `ValueError: insecure string pickle`.

Thank you in advance!

### Update

Thank you all. I didn't try joblib, it works after setting `protocol=2`.

Comment: Thats wierd. Never happened to me even though i've written similar sizes of dump files. Its interesting that "occasionally" the file gets stored. Since you have 16G of RAM, can you try cPickle.dumps() and see what length of string are you actually getting?
Also, you get the "insecure string pickle" error when you are trying to read from a file that has not been closed yet.

Comment: @hrs this time I successfully saved the files, it's around 2G. Don't know why the program uses more than 50% of the memory to save it. May be sometimes the memory is occupied by other programs so there isn't enough left. I'll try one more time to see what happens. And regrading the `insecure string pickle` error, I'm using `with` to open the file and actually that program is closed before reading.

Comment: hmm, okay.
cPickle.dump copies the object into a string and then writes the file. That might be the reason that it takes too much memory.

Comment: Try pickling with [`joblib.dump`](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html), it should be smarter about large NumPy arrays than standard pickle.

Comment: @larsmans I had a nasty MemoryError while using `joblib.dump(model,file,compress=3)` The scikit-learn model is a random forest with ~thousands of trees. I will try with `compress=2`

Comment: Edit: 'compress=2' fails because, well, it's no available in joblib.v8.4. I don't want to screw scikit-learn by manually installing 9.3

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use out-of-core classifiers from sci-kit learn. These are batch learning algorithms, stores the model output as compressed sparse matrix and are very time efficient.

To start with, the following link really helped me.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html